# LLSimpleCamera flash button label rotate Text gives "..."

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS app using [LLSimpleCamera](https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera).

What I'm trying to do is when I orientate the camera in either landscape way, the icons and buttons rotate as well. I've got that working except for one part!

You can see here that the button has both a imageView and a textLabel ('Off'):
[image]

When I rotate my phone, the Off turns into ellipses. "...":

[image]

In the portrait orientation, it looks fine:

[image]

I rotated the other buttons and labels correctly, just not this one. I suspect that since the flash image and text is part of ONE button, it causes some problems?

Relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.hasShownConsentAlert = NO;
    self.flashButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    UIImage *flashImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CameraFlashIcon"];
    [self.flashButton setImage:[flashImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.flashButton.imageView setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

 ...

- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation) orientation {

    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];


switch (orientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: {
     ....
    }
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown: {
     ....
    }
        break;
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft: {
        self.flashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        self.flashButton.titleLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
...
```

I've also tried to shrink the font, which makes the ellipses SHRINK, but the word still does not show up.

**My biggest question would be**: Why does it turn into ellipses?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @sschale, I know why it turns to ellipses.

My code did not really change. New Image update:

[image]

Now is there a way to format the text so the whole text fits in? Changing the height (44), font size, Content Hugging Priority/Content Compression Resistance Priority did not help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that it is a width issue and because the whole word can't fit, it turns into `...` due to its lineBreakMode. What happens if you set `yourTextLable.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping` to see how much is visible?

Comment: Thanks so much! That helps me a lot and I can see that it is cut off (See edit). Is there a way you know so that it doesn't get cut off? Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UILabel` has an intrinsic height and width given its `text`. Delete the concrete set attributes, and it should take care of the rest. Because it changes orientations, the initial constraints goof it up, but if you remove them, it automatically fixes them.